# MVC, Only show first item for each different Name in foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, foreach

I have a list containing 6 items (rows). First column gives the property "Name" in each row:

---

**Name**

item1

item1

item1

item2

item2

item2

---

Is it possible to use a foreach loop to only show the first item of each different name so I get something like this:

---

item1

item2

---

I have tried using Model.Take(1) but this only shows the first item in the entire list.

My current loop looks like this:

```
foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</p>
    }
```

Comment: In your controller, where you populate the model, you need to use `.Distinct(x => x.Name)` to remove the duplicates. You _can_ do it in the view but it's better to pass the correct data in the first place

Comment: Use a container/array/vector, traverse and check if the new value already exits or not. simple enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need grouping:

```
@{
   var result = Model.GroupBy(x=>x.Name);

}
```

and then iterate on `result` for rendering.

```
@foeach(var item in result)
{
  <span>@item.Key</span>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Distinct(m => m.Name).OrderBy(m => m.Name))
{
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</p>
}
```